# Finding records in a date range

Tags: sql

If I want to find the active records that are in a date range, do I need to join the table to itsself or just a flat where clause is enough?
the schema of table is something like:

```
active_ind  bool
beg_dt_tm   datetime
end_dt_dm   datetime
```

and the query is passing in a datetime param to find the records in that range, so I was wondering a psedu-sql like this is enough or do I need to join to the table and why?

```
select * 
from   MyTable mt
where  mt.active_ind = true 
and    param between mt.beg_dt_tm and mt.end_dt_tm
```

Comment: This should be enough.

Comment: @juergend : Oh it was a typo. Thanks for catching it. fixed.

Comment: Also make sure you have an index on the two date fields or you risk big slowness with large numbers of rows.

Comment: Please never use `BETWEEN` for ranges.  Always use 'lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive' - so `param >= mt.beg_dt_tm AND param < mt.end_dt_tm` (besides off-by-one errors, there are potentially data-conversion issues per-platform).  This also tends to apply to the values you _store_, as well - the end date should probably be conceptually an 'ends before' date.  Also, don't encode column names with their datatypes - you should probably use something like `isActive`, `beganAt`, and `endedBy`

Answer (score 0):

You must not use BETWEEN in such a case.
Do like this:

```
select * 
from MyTable mt
where
    mt.beg_dt_tm >= param and 
    mt.end_dt_tm <= param
```